# Display strings from blocks layout?

Tags: module, layout, theme

Here is the [link](http://attin.netlogiq.info/magento/index.php/helloworld) with the result. 
In the image you can see the path of all files :

[image]

this is my Attila3->HelloWorld->Block->HelloWorld.php file :

```
<?php   
class Attila3_HelloWorld_Block_Index extends Mage_Core_Block_Template{   
}
```

this is my Attila3->HelloWorld->controllers->IndexController.php file:

```
<?php
class Attila3_HelloWorld_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{
    public function IndexAction() {

      $this->loadLayout();   
      $this->getLayout()->getBlock("head")->setTitle($this->__("My title"));
            $breadcrumbs = $this->getLayout()->getBlock("breadcrumbs");
      $breadcrumbs->addCrumb("home", array(
                "label" => $this->__("Home Page"),
                "title" => $this->__("Home Page"),
                "link"  => Mage::getBaseUrl()
           ));

      $breadcrumbs->addCrumb("my title", array(
                "label" => $this->__("My title"),
                "title" => $this->__("My title")
           ));

      $this->renderLayout(); 

    }
}
```

this is my Attila3->HelloWorld->etc->config.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Attila3_HelloWorld>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Attila3_HelloWorld>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <helloworld>
        <use>standard</use>
          <args>
            <module>Attila3_HelloWorld</module>
            <frontName>helloworld</frontName>
          </args>
      </helloworld>
    </routers>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <helloworld>
              <file>helloworld.xml</file>
            </helloworld>
        </updates>
    </layout>
  </frontend>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <helloworld>
        <class>Attila3_HelloWorld_Helper</class>
      </helloworld>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
      <helloworld>
        <class>Attila3_HelloWorld_Block</class>
      </helloworld>
    </blocks>
  </global>
</config>
```

this is my Attila3->HelloWorld->Helper->Data.php file:

```
<?php
class Attila3_HelloWorld_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

this is my Attila3->layout->helloworld.xml file from "frontend":

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>   
<layout version="0.1.0">   
  <helloworld_index_index>   
    <reference name="root">   
      <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>   
    </reference>   
    <reference name="content">   
      <block type="helloworld/index" name="helloworld_index" template="helloworld/index.phtml"/>   
    </reference>   
  </helloworld_index_index>   
</layout>
```

this is my Attila3->template->helloworld->index.phtml file from "frontend":

```
<p class ="test">Hello World ! I am a Magento Guy.</p>
```

this is my etc/modules/Attila3_HelloWorld.xml content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Attila3_HelloWorld>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Attila3_HelloWorld>
  </modules>
</config>
```

I selected the Attila3 theme from admin->design and cleared the caches. and this is the result : 
[image]
What im doing wrong ??? I want to display the string "Magento guy ....." thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Block class file path is `Attila3/HelloWorld/Block/HelloWorld.php` but the classname is `Attila3_HelloWorld_Block_Index`. Change the filename to `Index.php` and it should work